# 80’s/90’s movie scene where a taxi driver watches a group board a spaceship at night

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

'80s, maybe early '90s.  I remember a scene where a taxi driver, at night, observes a group walking onto a spaceship, maybe in a park setting.  The group is dressed in human civilian clothes, the taxi driver gets out to watch, then says something like "They wear Nike's!"

At this point I can't remember if it was a movie or something on TV.  I've rewatched *Flight of the Navigator*, *Cocoon*, *Cocoon: The Return*, *They Live*, *Explorers*, *E.T.*, *The Last Starfighter*, and the TV movie *V* but still haven't figured it out.

Comment: Hmm. The spaceship in a park reminds me of *Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home*, but I don't remember any references to Nikes. Also, the ship was invisible.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/whatmoviewasthat/comments/i141y0/80s_scifi_movie/ - Last time you posted this, you said it might be "sneakers", not "Nikes"

Comment: Just a guess because I've not seen it, but maybe it's the 1995 version of The Invaders. https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112018/

Comment: Can you describe the spaceship? Rocket, space shuttle, flying saucer?

Answer (score 7):

Its from a tv show miniseries called 'Something Is Out There'. You can watch it here: https://archive.org/details/something-is-out-there-1988-mini-series
The show isn't great, but d'Abo is as cute as ever.

The bit you're referring to is in part2 at 1h5m30s.

Hope you could help me with how I ended up here - i was googling whether  "They were Nike's" was a reference to some other advert or tv show.